# Apache reverse proxy href paths not updating

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I'm setting up a very basic reverse proxy. It's working fine for the first login page.

Here is the config.

Client       > Proxy         > WebServer
192.168.10.5 > 192.168.15.20 > 192.168.5.51

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.5.51:8080/
```

Once the user is logged on, on the page all links path is with the WebServer's IP

In normal case the URI should be "http://192.168.15.20" but it comes up after login as "http://192.168.5.51:8080"

Is there any additional configuration directive I'm missing.?

Answer (score 0):

To update the response headers of your backend with the address of your reverse proxy, add a `ProxyPassReverse` directive below your `ProxyPass`:

```
ProxyPass        / http://192.168.5.51:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.5.51:8080/
```

Related:

- [ProxyPassReverse Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) (Apache Documentation)
- [Simple reverse proxying](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/reverse_proxy.html#simple) (Apache Reverse Proxy Guide)